# Performing jquery on knockout.js json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to pull in a number from json using knockout.js and then using jquery to adjust my progress bar.

It works when manually entering the number into the html. It does not work when bringing in the number with json.

I am not sure if this is a conflict with knockout/json and jquery or if my code is wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/5Q9pK/

```
// Knockout.js - bring in number of days from json
// -------------------------
// Here's my data model
var viewModel;
$.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/daysDue/50', function (data) {
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

// Progress Bar - adjust width of progress bar according to number of days
// -------------------------
$('#paging1 ul li').each(function () {
    // progress bar
    // find number of days until due date
    var progBarValue = $(this).find('.days-due').text();
    // limit days due to no more than 100%
    progBarValue = progBarValue > 100 ? 98 : progBarValue;
    // set progress bar width
    $(this).find('.bar').width((100 - progBarValue) +'%');

    // set class of progress bar for color based on days due
    if (progBarValue >= 75) {
       $(this).find('.progress').removeClass('progress-warning progress-danger').addClass('progress-success');
       $(this).find('.DueDate').removeClass('urgent');
    } else  if (progBarValue >= 25 && progBarValue <= 74) {
       $(this).find('.progress').removeClass('progress-success progress-danger').addClass('progress-warning');
       $(this).find('.DueDate').removeClass('urgent');
    } else if (progBarValue <= 24) {
       $(this).find('.progress').removeClass('progress-warning progress-success').addClass('progress-danger');
       $(this).find('.DueDate').addClass('urgent');
    }
});
```

Comment: I would debug into this line `viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);` and inspect the `data` variable. I suspect that the data coming back is binding differently (or possibly not at all) like you inspect.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way. However, there is no point in loading your data in a knockout viewModel if you plan on manipulating the DOM with jQuery. Have you considered doing the following:

### Use computed observables for width and class

```
var viewModel;
$.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/daysDue/50', function (data) {
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    viewModel.progressBarWidth = ko.computed(function() { 
        return 100 - this.daysDue() + '%'
    }, this);
    viewModel.progressBarClass = ko.computed(function() {
        // note if (100 - x) >= 75, then x <= 25, etc.
        if (this.daysDue() <= 25) { return 'classa'; }
        else if (this.daysDue() > 25 && this.daysDue() <= 75) { return 'classb'; }
        else { return 'classc'; }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Now, you have a computed observables that compute the two values you're interested in, width and class.

### DOM bindings and CSS

I'm not sure how your DOM is structured, but I'll take a guess.

```
<!-- container -->
<div data-bind="css: progressBarClass">
    <!-- progress bar -->
    <div class="progress" data-bind="style: { width: progressBarWidth }"></div>
    <!-- text -->
    <div class="DueDate" data-bind="text: daysDue"></div>
</div>
```

Then all that is left is to set up the classes in CSS to look to the parent for declaration. So for example, for the >= 75 days due case you could have:

```
.classa > .progress 
{
    // progress bar style, red or whatever
}
.classa .DueDate
{ 
    // text style, red or whatever
}
```

Comment: So you are saying that knockout.js and jquery do conflict? Care to put up a fiddle example?

Comment: I don't think the point is that they *conflict*, but that they can *serve the same purpose* in this. If you're introducing KO in your app, you may as well use it for keeping the progress bars in synch with your view model instead of manually updating them with jQuery. (+1 btw :D)

Comment: Exactly. Both tools are able to modify your DOM when your data models change. I strongly prefer knockout to jQuery for this task, though. Knockout enables you to tell parts of your DOM what data model changes to look out for and how to react for them. jQuery requires that you watch the data model changes and then tell your DOM how to react to them. 

jQuery serves as much more than a UI tool, of course, so it typically makes sense to use jQuery even if you're using Knockout; you just use it for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @MatthewJamesDavis is great, because it's a much cleaner way to tackle the situation.

However, the issue at hand and the actual question is probably why the jQuery `text()` function isn't finding the proper "50" that KO has bound to the span. The reason is that the `getJSON` method fires way later than the actual `each` that sets the progress bars. You can "solve" this by wrapping that bit in a function that's called at the proper time:

```
var viewModel;
$.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/daysDue/50', function (data) {
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    updateProgressBars(); // NEW
});

function updateProgressBars() { // NEW
    $('#paging1 ul li').each(function () {
        // As before...
    });
} // NEW
```

Now, the progress bars are updated *after* you get your data with jQuery.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Q9pK/17/) for a demo.

Again though, it's way better to *bind* the appropriate progress-bar attributes with KO instead of manually doing it with jQuery.